# Using each to iterate over the passed in data

Tags: jquery-templates, jquery

If an array is passed to a jquery template directly(without it being a property of an object) how do I iterate over it?

ex:

```
var hired=[{name:'Jack'}, {name:'Jack'}, {name:'Jack'}]
```

This is the data passed to the template below:

```
Template Start
<div> 

<table> 

{{each $data}}

<tr>
    <td width="250" align="left">${$value.name}</th>
    <td width="150" align="center">${$value.name}</th>
    <td width="60" align="center">${$value.name}</th>
</tr>
{{/each}}

</table>

</div>

Template End
```

Since there is no property name to refer to the passed in data, I tried using $data but it doesn't work. How can I get access to the array here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure how jQuery templates work but in javaScript arrays behave  like object literals whose properties are element indexes. So the array in your example is the same (from the each loop point of view) as the object {0:{name:'Jack'}, 1:{name:'Jack'}, 2:{name:'Jack'}}

Answer (score 2):

If you pass an array to `tmpl`, it will automatically apply the template to each element. Isn't that what you want?

```
var hired = [{name:'Jack'}, {name:'Jack'}, {name:'Jack'}];
```

With template:

```
<script id="hired-template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <!-- I think you originally closed these with 'th' by mistake. -->
        <td width="250" align="left">${name}</td>
        <td width="150" align="center">${name}</td>
        <td width="60" align="center">${name}</td>
    </tr>
</script>

<table id="hired-table"></table>
```

This should allow you to do:

```
$('#hired-template').tmpl(hired).appendTo('#hired-table');
```

And get:

```
<table id="hired-table">
    <tr>
        <td width="250" align="left">Jack</td>
        <td width="150" align="center">Jack</td>
        <td width="60" align="center">Jack</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="250" align="left">Jack</td>
        <td width="150" align="center">Jack</td>
        <td width="60" align="center">Jack</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="250" align="left">Jack</td>
        <td width="150" align="center">Jack</td>
        <td width="60" align="center">Jack</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Of course, I'm not sure if you meant to have "Jack" appear a total of nine times; but that seems to be what your code would do if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am aware of this but in my case I cant render the template multiple times nor can I use subtemplates. Isnt there a way to get hold of the data object passed? I have edited my template in the question.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<table id="tableID">
</table>
```

javascript:

```
var hired=[{name:'Jack'}, {name:'Jimmy'}, {name:'Ron'}]

    for( var i=0; i < hired.length; i++ ) {
        $( "#tableID" ).append(
          "<tr> \
            <td width=\"250\" align=\"left\">" + hired[ i ].name + "</td> \
            <td width=\"150\" align=\"center\"> " + hired[ i ].name + " </td> \
            <td width=\"60\" align=\"center\"> " + hired[ i ].name + " </td> \
           </tr>"
        );
    };
```

let me know if you can't understand something.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a jquery template specific answer.